# Date and time picker in trinidad JSF?

Tags: jsf, myfaces, trinidad

tr:inputDate tag allows entering only dates. 
Could not find a tag to enter date along with time.

What has been tried?

1> Used pattern="dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss" in tr:inputDate
2> tr:convertDateTime tag to see if time picker is displayed.
Unfortunately both these aproaches did not work.

Which tag or a way should be used to allow entering time along with the date in apache MyFaces trinidad?

Comment: I think you have to build it on your own.... http://myfaces.apache.org/trinidad/trinidad-api/tagdoc/tr_inputDate.html

Comment: Can i use primefaces pe:timePicker tag with MyFaces?

Comment: I can't tell you. I haven't worked with primefaces so far.

Comment: okay, I'll try creating a custom tag using MyFacesbuilder plugin.